# Android videoview can't play this video error on android 4.3

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to use videoView to play remote video, after I added the videoView in the app, it works fine on Samsung s6 but When I try on google s2 it just doesn't play the video, shows the message can't play this video. not sure what's the reason for it. it works with 3gp files, with mp4, it doesn't work get the error says couldn't open file on client side, try server side.

if I add the video to the project folder and play video it works, when when upload video onto server and load from URL is the not working

below is the code that I use, hope to get some help, thanks

```
 videoPlayer =(VideoView)mView.findViewById(R.id.home_page_video_view);
videoPlayer.setVideoPath(videoUrl);
videoPlayer.start();
videoPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(PreparedListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

your casting to VideoPlayer and not VideoView, is VideoPlayer a samsung sdk specific. an example of playing a video file with android VideoView can be found here - http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-videoview-example/

Comment: VideoPlayer is a custom file that I created extends VideoView. I switched back VideoView, it is still not working, it has worked when I first added, but since yesterday, it just stopped working and haven't changed any code